# how to truncate an array of uint8 rather than overflow, when adding a value?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, integer-overflow, numpy-ndarray

I would like to implement a tool to adjust the brightness of a RGB image, which is simply a *(N, M, 3)*-shaped numpy array of dtype `uint8`.

The algorithm is really simple, I'm just adding an integer in range `[-255, 255]` to all pixels of my images.

Unfortunately, I also need to truncate the resulting pixel value to stay in range [0, 255], and numpy makes the array overflow when I'm adding the value.

Is there a way to add the brightness and take care of truncating the result without creating an intermediary array or using an ugly loop?

I'm working with large images, so I need to be efficient.

Comment: np.clip([-1, 1, 255, 256], 0, 255) ….  array([  0,   1, 255, 255]) but check the help and make sure you specify the output dtype properly

Comment: @nan that requires creating an intermediary array of larger dtype. If my data is 1GB of uint8, it will use up to 2GB more memory of uint16.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late but I've used a convenient non-linear function (arctan) instead of clipping the overflow values:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

factor = 3
c = 512 / np.pi  # a constant to be used along with arctan

adjusted_image = np.arctan(data/c * factor) * c
Image.fromarray(adjusted_image.astype(np.int8), 'RGB')
```

The non-linear function can be fine-tuned, indeed; take this as an example for testing.